# my data is not fetch in db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, group-by

My problem is that these query always run on my local server but not don't run online.

```
SELECT order_number, max(cart_datetime) maxdate, sum(cart_total), cart_u_id
FROM addtocart_2
WHERE cart_u_id ='$_SESSION[UserId]'
GROUP BY cart_datetime desc limit 1
```

Online server showing on this line below:

> 1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT
>   list contains nonaggregated column
>   'gloriast_gloria.addtocart_2.order_number'; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

[image]

Comment: probably there is different setup between your local server and online server

Comment: Check versions of `mysql` at both places.

Comment: Try to use `ANY_VALUE(order_number)` and `ANY_VALUE(cart_u_id)` In SELECT ...

Comment: Do you have access to the server's mysql using phpmyadmin or like that?

Answer (score 1):

In the text exception raised by MYSQL you have the answer :-)

> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

In your local DB, you have set different mode. Please refer to MySQL documentation to change that:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your server's mysql has `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enabled.

You can disable it by running the following query in your server.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Then your query should work. If you want to know why it happens, refer to the mysql documentation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

It explains how and why this happens and how to solve this :)

Hope it helps.